# How to get related objects?

Tags: django, django-models

I have models:

```
class Model_1(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(...)

class Model_2(models.Model):
    [...]
    m1 = models.ManyToManyField(Model_1, blank=True, null=True)

class Model_3(models.Model):
    [...]
    m1 = models.ForeignKey(Model_1)
```

and I want to get all Model_3 objects simple. So far I did in this way:

```
obj = Model_2.objects.filter(...)
this_i_want = []
for my2 in obj:
    for my1 in my2.m1.all():
        objects = Model_3.objects.filter(m1=my1)
        for o in objects:
            this_i_want.append(o)
```

How to do it simplest? I must go from Model_2.

Comment: Think about it in two steps.  Step 1 - get a list of all the m1 that you want - try using values("m1").distinct(), Step 2 - pull out all the Model_3 where m1 is IN the list of m1s you collected in Step 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Model_3.objects.filter(m1__model_2__in=Model_2.objects.all())
```